# Find flight when ticket bought through unknown third-party but code lost?

Tags: air-travel

Yesterday I mistyped the code of my flight in my calendar: etc VVF31, but the right one was VVF3I. I did not remember which carrier it was. I did not remember which third-party site I bought the flight from. Finally, I found the right code by error-and-trial but it took some time.

- I knew: name, and date,
- but not airline exactly. I knew that it is either American airlines, Finnair or airbaltic flight.
- I did not have my eticket, PNR nor carrier, nor agency/site.

Assume

- You cannot your email where the email confirmation was sent.
- You cannot find the payment on your bank details.

Comment: I really don't understand what is the question here. If you have the ticket, you know the flight?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Search your browser history?

Comment: Pretty much every booking service will send you an email confirmation, unless you also mistyped your email address. Is there a reason you can't search your email for the confirmation, which will provide all the flight details for you?

Comment: How did you pay for it?  Normally your bank or credit card would be able to help you identify and contact any merchant that you have paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, you lose your ticket if you lose the confirmation email, the travel code, cannot find the payment details (fast enough) IF you do not know where you travel from. 
So because of privacy issue, you cannot checkin online only with your lastname i.e. without the code in the given list of airlines. 
BUT you can still make checkin at the airport if you know the date, travel locations and have your passport, so just go to the airport.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, I had a friend whom I know booked a flight on June 2nd to the US. Now I want to play a trick on him by cancelling the flight in his name. Please tell me how to find the booking code so I can pull this off.

Did I get your question right?

Comment: No, this is not the point of the thread. You still have your passport to prove your identity or online measures to do it.

Comment: @Léo Léopold Hertz - Please explain "online measures". Nobody asks for your passport when cancelling and rebooking a flight, if you can present enought personal information. This is exactly why you need this personal information AND the flight code to access your flight online.